# AccessViolationException in EmguCV

Tags: c#, .net, opencv, c#-4.0, emgucv

I'm currently scanning few images and store ROIs in a `List`. Now I loop through the list and check if the ROI has a bar code in it. It works with few images and throws an `AccessViolationException` at **converting mat to image** for others and it is not getting caught in the catch block.

The below code is used to check if bar code exists.

```
List<Mat> subMats = new List<Mat>();

Mat mat = new Mat(image.Mat, enlargeROI(image.Mat,NEWRECTANGLE,PADDING));

subMats.Add(mat);


using (var mImage = new Image<Bgr, byte>(image.Width, image.Height))
                    {
                        var barcodeReader = new BarcodeReader();

                        foreach (var matt in subMats)
                        {
                            //TODO : check if the submat is a barcode                    
                            try
                            {

                                Image<Bgr, byte> img = matt.ToImage<Bgr, byte>(); // EXCEPTION THROWN AT THIS LINE

                                Bitmap bmp = img.ToBitmap();

                                if (barcodeReader.Decode(bmp) != null)
                                {
                                    CvInvoke.Rectangle(image, NEWRECTANGLE, new MCvScalar(0.0, 0.0, 0.0), -1);
                                }
                            }

                            catch (Exception e)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("**" + e.Message);
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

The Exception says

> "Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt."

Tried to read it using images like below, but it wouldn't detect the barcodes properly.

```
public static List<Rectangle> rois = new List<Rectangle>();
rois.Add(NEWRECTANGLE);


using (var mImage = image)
                    {

                        var barcodeReader = new BarcodeReader();

                        int count = 0;
                        foreach (var roi in rois)
                        {
                            //TODO : check if the submat is a barcode                    
                            try
                            {
                                mImage.ROI = roi;

                                Bitmap bmp = mImage.ToBitmap();

                                if (barcodeReader.Decode(bmp) != null)
                                {
                                    CvInvoke.Rectangle(image, NEWRECTANGLE, new MCvScalar(0.0, 0.0, 0.0), -1);
                                }
                            }

                            catch (Exception e)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("**" + e.Message);
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

What could go wrong? Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

**EDIT**

I have identified all my ROIs by finding contours. Looping through the contours I find the rectangles and store them in a `List`.

```
 CvInvoke.FindContours(fullGrad, contours, null, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.RetrType.List, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.ChainApproxMethod.ChainApproxNone);


                for (int i = 0; i < contours.Size; i++)
                {

                    if (CvInvoke.ContourArea(contours[i]) < 2000) {

                        continue;
                    }

                    RotatedRect RECT = CvInvoke.MinAreaRect(contours[i]);

                    PointF[] VERTIXES = RECT.GetVertices();

                            int X = (int)VERTIXES[1].X;
                            int Y = (int)VERTIXES[2].Y;
                            //OBTAIN RECTANGLE THAT SURROUNDS THE DETECTED CONTOUR
                            int WIDTH = (int)(VERTIXES[3].X - VERTIXES[1].X);
                            int HEIGHT = (int)(VERTIXES[0].Y - VERTIXES[2].Y);

                            Rectangle NEWRECTANGLE = new Rectangle(X, Y, WIDTH, HEIGHT);

                    Mat mat = new Mat(image.Mat, enlargeROI(image.Mat,NEWRECTANGLE,PADDING));

                    subMats.Add(mat);
```

Comment: How are you reading in your mats? it looks like you probbaly have read in a corrupted frame, or a null frame?

Comment: @GPPK please check my edit.

Comment: Hi, did you ever solve the problem? I have the same :/